# Merging converted dataframes from multiple series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I receive some data in 11 different pandas series. I need to combine the whole data into one pandas dataframe to carry out further analysis and reporting.

The format in which the data is received is as under:

```
Series1:
                        Sales
Item    Series  Year
A       Sal     2018    100
                2019    200
B       Sal     2018    300
                2019    400

Series2:
                        Purchases
Item    Series  Year
A       Pur     2018    50
                2019    100
B       Pur     2018    150
                2019    200

Series3:
                        Expenses
Product Series  Year
A       Exp     2019    100
B       Exp     2019    200
```

I have a number of series parameter. So, I created a loop where the following code merges two of the total series till the all series are merged. I have tried to consolidate all such series into one dataframe using this code:

```
df = pd.merge(df,series1,left_on=['Product','Year'],right_on=['Product','Year']).reset_index()
```

But even if we write separate lines for each two pairs for our example here, it will be:

```
df = pd.merge(series1,series2,left_on=['Product','Year'],right_on=['Product','Year']).reset_index()
df = pd.merge(df,series3,left_on=['Product','Year'],right_on=['Product','Year']).reset_index()
```

However the issue with this is:

1. It only allows to merge two series at a time.
2. When I merge the third series in this example, as it doesn't have data for 2018, instead of putting NULL there, it remove the 2018 rows for even the series 1 and series 2 data in the dataframe. So, I am only left with merged data from all three series for 2019.

I considered converting all the series to list individually and then converting those lists to a dictionary, which then is converted into a dataframe. That works, but requires a lot of effort and requires code change if number of series changes. So, this doesn't work for me.

Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `to_frame` method?

For example, you could use

```
df = pd.Series["a", "b", "c"]
df.to_frame()
```

to convert.

Try using this method in your data frame.

Here's it in the docs.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html

Comment: Yes. I tried that too. But that works for one series at a time. And once all series are individually converted to dataframes, I am again not sure how to proceed to merge all of them considering the multi-index with which the series will be converted.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
import pandas as pd

import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series([100, 200, 300, 400], index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A','A','B','B'],['1','1','2','2'], [2018, 2019, 2018, 2019]]))
s2 = pd.Series([50, 100, 150, 200], index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A','A','B','B'],['3','3','4','4'], [2018, 2019, 2018, 2019]]))
s3 = pd.Series([100, 200], index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A','B'],['5','6'], [2019,  2019]]))

df = pd.concat([s.droplevel(1) for s in [s1, s2, s3]], axis = 1)
```

```
            0   1   2
A   2018    100 50  NaN
    2019    200 100 100.0
B   2018    300 150 NaN
    2019    400 200 200.0
```

Comment: Hey Li. Thanks for the reply. This sure works, but my data has an extra index as mentioned in the question (called Series in the question), which changes for each pandas series.

Due to that, when I run concat, for me the output is duplicated for each series with NaN everywhere else.

I see that we can ignore index in concat, but can we do something to ignore only the second of the three index in the multiindexed series?

Or may be remove the second index before concat?

Comment: Yes you could remove the second index before concat. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Hey thanks for this. I ran into another problem here. A lot of series comes with data from varied level 3. So, in the multiindex level 3, the data has a lot of variation. This results in a dataframe which has a lot of NaN values.

I figured that if instead of keeping each series as columns in dataframe, if I made two columns for first level (A and B), kept second level (year) in the index, and made the series name as index in the dataframe to show values under A or B column. Is that possible? How to do that?